# Vuetify v-btn how to remove follow up slot span tag

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-slot, v-btn

I'm trying to **remove the span tag** which follow up in the **v-btn component provided by Vuetify**, that is **getting in the way of tracking** via HTML id attributes in analytics

Code provided below using UI component (v-btn) from Vuetify

```html
<v-btn
   id="btn-home-sectionSix-partner"
   to="/about/partnership"
   class="ma-2 HomeLastBtn textBtn text-center"
   outlined
   style="text-align: -webkit-center;"
 >Become a partner
</v-btn>
```

Renders the following in browser

```html
<a data-v-fae5bece="" 
 href="/about/partnership" 
 class="ma-2 HomeLastBtn textBtn text-center v-btn v-btn--outlined v-btn--router theme--light v-size--default" 
 id="btn-home-sectionSix-partner" 
 style="text-align: -webkit-center;"
>
 <span class="v-btn__content">
   Become a partner
 </span>
</a>
```

As mentioned above, I do not want the text in the `span` tag, but in the `a` tag directly

```html
<a data-v-fae5bece="" 
 href="/about/partnership" 
 class="ma-2 HomeLastBtn textBtn text-center v-btn v-btn--outlined v-btn--router theme--light v-size--default" 
 id="btn-home-sectionSix-partner" 
 style="text-align: -webkit-center;"
 >
  Become a partner
</a>
```

I have referred to the following sources but not getting the answer I want.

- [Vuetify V-Btn API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-btn/#slots)
- [How to use Vuetify Component Slot Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66962227/how-to-use-vuetify-component-slot-function)

Have also tried the following

```html
<a data-v-fae5bece="" 
  href="/about/partnership" 
  class="ma-2 HomeLastBtn textBtn text-center v-btn v-btn--outlined v-btn--router theme--light v-size--default" 
  id="btn-home-sectionSix-partner" 
  style="text-align: -webkit-center;"
>
 <template v-slot:default>
   Try For Free Now
 </template>
</a>
```

But leads to the same result above.

Thanks & appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `V-Btn` component have a `genContent` function implementation which will be invoked to generate the child elements while rendering the root component. By default it provides the following [implementation](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VBtn/VBtn.ts#L167).

```js
genContent (): VNode {
  return this.$createElement('span', {
    staticClass: 'v-btn__content',
  }, this.$slots.default)
}
```

As you can see it creates a `span` element with a static class `v-btn__content` .That's why the text is rendered with in the `span` tag.

So to answer your question, you might have to extend the `V-btn` component and provide your own implementation of `genContent` function. The [official doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions/#questions) provides a sample example([codepen](https://codepen.io/whoistobias/pen/yLNgjwy)) on how to extend the componet and override the `genContent`(which is copied below)

```js
// src/components/ActivateBtn
import { VBtn } from 'vuetify/lib'

export default {
  extends: VBtn,

  methods: {
    // Here we overwrite the genContent method of VBtn
    // to override the default genContent method
    genContent() {
      return this.$createElement('div', {
        staticClass: 'v-btn__contents'
      }, [
        'Activate ',
        this.$slots.default
      ])
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond. Wouldn't have approach it this way. But I have to ask further. How can I get to the solution I need? Cuz in the above example, it replaces span with div, but if I do not want to createElement. How can I just place the text value only?

Comment: @Tyler You can directly return the text as string from `genContent` function

Comment: Thanks. I accepted your response. I'll go ahead with figuring the genContent part